# It is possible to use Alexa Skill with Amazon Redshift?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am resposible for doing Alexa Skill on my company. We received a new Skill to do. This skill needs to contact the data that is saved on Amazon Redshift and Alexa will get information like "what was the number of sales on November?" things like that. It is possible to connect this two services: Alexa Skill and Amazon Redshift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and I've done it in the past but there is a catch.  Alexa can run Lambda functions and Lambda can access Redshift.  It is a little more complicated than that but not much.  I had Lambdas that started and stopped a Redshift cluster (plus a few more actions) and had an office Alexa enabled to run these.

The catch is the authentication model.  How do you know who is speaking to Alexa?  Anyone that can speak to an authorized Alexa can execute the Lambda functions you have defined for it to run.  Enabling Alexa to have access to anything sensitive is problematic and Redshift often contains sensitive information. We quickly disallowed Alexa from running these and just kept them executable from Slack.